# Formatting with Array[i] Logic

Tags: java, formatting, logic

I'm trying to build a program that prints 75 random caps and lowercase letters, 25 per line. I think I have all the logic worked out, but whenever I run it the formatting is all off and rather than printing 25 characters per line, it prints a random number. Here's my code so far:

```
char allLetters[] = new char[3700];

for(int i = 1; i <= 75; i++) { //Begin for loop

int max = 122;
int min = 65;

allLetters[i] = (char)(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);

if(i % 25 != 0){

if (allLetters[i] <= 90) {
    System.out.printf("%s,",allLetters[i]);
}

if (allLetters[i] >= 97) {
    System.out.printf("%s,",allLetters[i]);
}

} //Close if

else {

if (allLetters[i] <= 90) {
    System.out.printf("%s\n",allLetters[i]);
}

if (allLetters[i] >= 97) {
    System.out.printf("%s\n",allLetters[i]);
}

}

} //End for
```

Currently, the output is something like:

```
U,i,y,e,v,T,G,p,P,a,U,G,e,B,w,U,o,F,G,w,j,m,R
O,X,w,w,u,p,t,g,X,J,R,c,w,I,d,H,R,m,y,b,o
C,p,M,F,X,U,v,O,a,Y,F,E,x,s,x,k,C,b,D,R,r,H
```

I've tried using different variables besides i, playing around with numbers and  such but I can't seem to find the exact flaw in the logic that throws the formatting off. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your logic is that you are counting each chosen character even when you do not print it.  The ASCII characters falling between 90 and 97, exclusive, are not characters, and you rightfully skip printing them.  Yet the loop is still counting those iterations as if a valid letter has been printed.  This is resulting in an incorrect count in the output.

The workaround used in the code snippet below is to keep picking characters in a loop until we actually get a lowercase or uppercase letter.  Only then do we continue with your previous logic.

```
char allLetters[] = new char[3700];
int max = 122;
int min = 65;

for (int i = 1; i <= 75; i++) {
    char next;
    do {
        next = (char)(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
    } while (next > 90 && next < 97);
    allLetters[i] = next;
    if (i % 25 != 0) {
        System.out.printf("%s,", next);
    }
    else {
        System.out.printf("%s\n", next);
    }
}
```

### Demo

Comment: Wow, thanks a ton. Elegant and easy-to-understand for new dudes like me.

Comment: There is no need to use constants like `65`, `122`, `90`, and `97`. Just use `'A'`, `'z'`, `'Z'`, and `'a'`, to make their intent clear. Further, the “multiply `Math.random()` with constants” idiom is strongly discouraged. It’s error prone and this example demonstrates why. With `(Math.random() * (max - min) + min)`, you will never get `max`. I recommend using `ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max + 1)` instead. You can omit the type cast to `char` when you declare `next` as `int` and use `%c` instead of `%s` in `printf` and omit the obsolete array storage operation.

Answer (score 0):

Your two conditions that you put on your random characters, namely `allLetters[i] <= 90` and `allLetters[i] >= 97`, do not cover the entire interval of possible characters, which in your program is 65 to 122, inclusive. When a character between 91 and 96 gets generated, your program does not print anything. The probability of getting one of these six random characters is roughly 10%, so you get 21..23 characters printed.

If you really want to skip these six characters, fix the problem by using a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop, and increment the counter of printed characters only when you print something:

```
int printed = 0;
while (printed != 75) {
    char ch = (char)(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
    if (ch >= 91 && ch <= 96) continue;
    printed++;
    System.out.print(ch);
    if (printed % 25 == 0 {
        System.out.println();
    } else {
        System.out.print(',');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll look into using while loops.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at your problem, and there's a "clever" solution using Java 8+ `IntStream` and lambdas. Generate 75 random `int`(s) between `0` and `26`, map each value to a one-character `String` offset from either `'a'` or `'A'` by using `nextBoolean()` from `Random`. Collect that to a single seventy-five character `String`. Then print the three twenty-five character `substring`(s) we're interested in. Like,

```
Random rand = new Random();
String s = IntStream.generate(() -> rand.nextInt(26)).limit(75)
        .mapToObj(i -> Character.toString(
                rand.nextBoolean() ? (char) (i + 'a') : (char) (i + 'A')))
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
System.out.println(s.substring(0, 25));
System.out.println(s.substring(25, 50));
System.out.println(s.substring(50));
```

Comment: That's definitely interesting, but for now I'm trying to stick to simple for, if, and while logic. Thanks for taking the time to find a solution, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Mind that all `Random` instances already have stream factory methods. For this particular task, `ThreadLocalRandom` might be preferable to a synchronizing `Random`, hence, you can use `ThreadLocalRandom.current() .ints(75, 0, 26)`, then, reduce code duplication on the next step: `.mapToObj(i -> Character.toString((char) (i + ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextBoolean()? 'a': 'A'))`, though, I would prefer avoiding the boxing overhead, even when the code becomes slightly more complicated, i.e. `.collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append).toString()`…